# Need to display Excel Spreadsheet in html using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, ej2-syncfusion

I'm trying to display a spreadsheet by uploading the excel document using ej2-syncfusion(spreadsheet), The document is being displayed successfully but I'm not able to copy the index number of the cell. Is there any way I can get the index number when the user copies a certain cell?

[This is the output of syncfusion, I want the output as c1-c4 when the user copies the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ipRJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after adding the following to angular.json

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/assets/styles"
  ]
```